# Why the image not getting displayed in the background of the div?

Tags: css

CSS file:-

```
 <style type="text/css">

.sprite div{
width: 728px; 
height: 243px; 
}    

.sprite 
     a:hover{ display: block; 
                    width: 728px; 
                    height: 243px; 
                    background-image: url(images/image.jpg); 
                    background-repeat: no-repeat; }
     .sp_ID1  
     {
        background-position: 0px 0px; 
     } 
    .sp_ID2
    {
         background-position: 0px -245px; 
     } 

     .sp_ID3
    {
         background-position: 0px -492px; 
     } 

     .sp_ID4
    {
         background-position: 0px -737px; 
     } 

     .sp_ID5
    {
         background-position: 0px -1000px; 
     } 

     .sp_ID6
    {
         background-position: 0px -200px; 
     } 
    </style
```

HTML :-

```
<div class="sprite>"
    <span class="sprite sp_ID1"><a href=#>Link1</a></span> <br /><br />

         <span class="sprite sp_ID2"><a href=#>Link2</a></span> <br /> <br />

         <span class="sprite sp_ID3"> <a href=#>Link3</a></span> <br /><br />

         <span class="sprite sp_ID4"> <a href=#>Link4</a></span> <br /><br />

         <span class="sprite sp_ID5"> <a href=#>Link5</a></span> <br />
</div>
```

The parts of images of this CSS sprite are appearing only as the background of the anchor tags..I want the parts of [this](http://www.flickr.com/photos/50525207@N02/5064283850/) CSS sprite to appear as the bground of the div..basically trying to implement rollover images using Sprites..

What I want is something like [this](http://www.flickr.com/photos/50525207@N02/5063686801/) .....Grey colored image to appear in the background when mouse is hovered over "Link1", Green colored image to appear when mouse is hovered over "Link2" and so on...plz someone tell me what am I doing wrong ? Been trying to make it work since yesterday but in vain...plz help..Thanks.

Comment: Duplicate of [Need help with CSS Sprites plz](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3896185/need-help-with-css-sprites-plz-closed) and [Problem implementing CSS Sprite](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3895848/problem-implementing-css-sprite) -- see [Is reposting a question the only way to get answers if help is urgently needed and there's no activity on the original?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67083/is-reposting-a-question-the-only-way-to-get-answers-if-help-is-urgently-needed-an) for background info.

Comment: Let me see if I get this right. You want that list of links and want the whole gray area to change background colour (background image) when they're being hovered?

Comment: New link since [a power outage](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67114/stack-overflow-outage) gave the duplicates a new id: [Need help with CSS Sprites plz](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3896522/need-help-with-css-sprites-plz-closed).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Happy Soul, I tried to explain this to you in [the other copy of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3895848/problem-implementing-css-sprite) but got voted down when you couldn't figure it out:

`.sprite a:hover` has your background image.

`.sp_ID1` (the same element as `.sprite`) is getting the image positioning, but it has no background image.

It's unclear what you really want, but there are several problems, I think you need to take a step back and try to understand what you're doing:

1. You're targeting different elements for the background image and the image positioning.
2. The `a` element has no dimensions or positioning until it's hovered.
3. There is no background-image on the `a` element until it's hovered.
4. Your added `.sprite div` doesn't target any elements, there is no `div` inside your `.sprite`

Comment: +1 for patience, even though I feel one should not answer duplicate questions, but just vote to get them closed.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want to do is add :hover to each of the span classes, not to the anchor tag.